# ASP.NET MVC foreach prints multiple entries

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

foreach loop prints all the entries in the table, I need it to print only once the only correct data.

```
    @foreach(JiraAssignee assignee in Model.JiraAssignee)
    {
       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>assignee.DisplayName)
       break;
    }
```

and the break statement makes it print only the first data. in the table.
Is there any conditional statement that I can check to print only once. or if you have any correction?

Comment: If you only want to do something once, why do you have a loop?  Loops are for doing things many times.

Comment: you can have if condition within a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is collection (IEnumerable or List)

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.JiraAssignee.FirstOrDefault().DisplayName)
```

ELse following will be code

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.JiraAssignee.DisplayName)
```

Please mark as answer If I helped

Answer (score 0):

> I need it to print only once

Then don't use a loop.  Loops are for *looping*, doing things multiple times.

Just print the value once:

```
@if (Model.JiraAssignee.Count() > 0)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.JiraAssignee.First().DisplayName)
}
```